# python close mdf(.mf4) file

Tags: asammdf

I read a mf4 file using asammdf package. I want to delete this file after doing some edits but failed. The error shows: This file is in use by another program and cannot be accessed by the process. I wonder how to close a mf4 file before delete.

`from asammdf import MDF`
`mdf = MDF(path)`

Answer (score 1):

```
from asammdf import MDF
mdf = MDF(path)
# .... something something
mdf.close()
```

Comment: I didn't find mdf.close() but use another one: mdf.__del__() to correctly close this file.

Comment: I struggled with it as I filtered my mdf `mdf0 = mdf0.filter(channels)` before closing it and this did not work. But it works if you do not change the mdf file reference before closing, thanks!